# Google Script Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the line below to send an email with word attachments in google script but for some reason only the owner [me] can run the code below and I do get the email with the attachments. For a normal user the below code does not execute and I did authorize the script on my account and the users account. Since it works for me I'm thinking it must be an authorization issue. It also used to work for the users as well.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Your Files - " + folder.getName(),
        "Please find your files attached.", {attachments: attachFiles});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

do you run this script in the authority of the connected user or you (the script owner) ? If it is the case, please change it to "User accessing web application".

Can you give more details please ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an add on to Sheets / Forms you may need to share the sheet with the user in addition. Is the user given a prompt when they try to access the script? What error message do they see?

Is "var email" a single email address or multiple?

If this is a published web app make sure save and publish the latest version as you run the /dev and the user sees the /exec
File > Manage Versions
Save a new Version
Publish > Deploy as Web App
Update with latest Project Version

Answer (score 1):

When publishing or deploying, did you forget to change the execution behavior to "User accessing web application" ?